# How can I serve up some simple web pages to show status / interact with a .net application?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, webserver

I have a (C++-CLI) .net (v2.0) application which collects data and I'd like to serve that information via a simple set of web pages.

Eventually I'd like a mechanism to interact with the application, but for now just serving up information would be good.

I couldn't see and obvious way to serve them direct from the app but if there are ways of interacting with an external (lightweight) web server that would be an acceptable solution too (I imagine writing a custom module which shares memory or something along those lines).

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just save that data to a file and create a php/ajax to parse it and deliver to the client's browser?

Comment: +1: That sounds like quite a neat way of doing a one-directional link at least.

Comment: If you want a client to request new data, just make a php script which will run the program and then parse new data. Or make A cronjob, or even easier run the program and get new data every time the client connects to a particular php page... there is a lot you can do.

Comment: The application will always be running (collecting data) and the normal method of interaction is via some bespoke software over a tcp connection.

Comment: if its always running, then its not efficient to save to a file... it obviously collects @ some periods of time, so it may make sense to make a database and enter new *changed* values, that way you can also provide statistics, if you need it /etc P.S. I have similar program running on my server and I use database, - works like a charm.